# async and set timeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, async.js

I am having some problem using the `settimeout()` in my function. I am new  to async. No matter how much I try I just can't make the timeout work. My code works perfect so that is not the problem. I need the request to execute every 10 seconds. Thanks for the help.

```
function getContent() {

function getPelicula(pelicula, donePelicula) {
            var peli = pelicula.title;

            //request id
            request({

              url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + peli + "&api_key=3e2709c4c051b07326f1080b90e283b4&language=en=ES&page=1&include_adult=false",
              method: "GET",
              json: true,
            }, function(error, res, body) {
              if (error) {
                console.error('Error getPelicula: ', error);
                return;
              }
              var control = body.results.length;
              if (control > 0) {


                var year_base = pelicula.launch_year;
                var id = body.results[0].id;
                var year = body.results[0].release_date;
                var d = new Date(year);
                var year_solo = d.getFullYear();

                if (year_base == year_solo) {
                  pelicula.id = id;
                  pelicula.year_pagina = year_solo;

                }

              } else {
                pelicula.id = null;
                pelicula.year_pagina = null;
              }
              donePelicula();

            });
          }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use `setTimeout()`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Where's the `setTimeout()`? It looks like you are using async.js, but where is the call for that also?

Comment: Looking at your code, I can see that you're accessing The Movie DB's API. I'm not sure you should be polling it on a 10 second interval. Perhaps do it on a manual reset. Additionally, I doubt the data at that api endpoint your accessing will even be updated that often.

Comment: Also, you REALLY SHOULD NOT include api key's in any public forum.

Comment: lol dont worry about api key i have no data on the account, its to take data form a page.

Comment: no im using a data base to cross the data from the api, its a one time job but i cant do to many request, the api key has 40 request every 20 seconds

Answer (score 3):

To do something in a loop, use `setInterval`.

UPD:

In general, there're two ways of executing some code in loop

1 `setTimeout` :

```
var someTimer = setTimeout(function sayHello(){
    console.log("hello!");
    someTimer = setTimeout(sayHello, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Notice that `someTimer` variable is needed to stop the looping process if you need: `clearTimeout(someTimer)`

2 `setInterval`:

```
var someIntervalTimer = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("I'm triggered by setInterval function!");
}, 2000);
```

Invoke `clearInterval(someIntervalTimer)` to stop the looping

Both functions are treated as properties of the global Window variable. By default, the following code works:

```
var window = this;
console.log("type of setTimeout: " + typeof window.setTimeout);
console.log("type of setInterval: " + typeof window.setInterval);
```

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of how to use `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in another function so:

```
          domore(pelicula,donePelicula);

          function domore(pelicula,donePelicula) {

                // 1 second
                var timeout = 1000;
                for (var i = 1; i < pelicula.length; i++) {

                    createData(pelicula[i],donePelicula,timeout);
                    timeout = timeout + 800;

                }
            }

          function createData(peli,donePelicula,timeout) {
            setTimeout(function() { getData(peli,donePelicula); }, timeout);
          }


          function getData(peli,donePelicula) {
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            txtFile.open("GET", "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=" + peli + "&api_key=3e2709c4c051b07326f1080b90e283b4&language=en=ES&page=1&include_adult=false", true);
            txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
                    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.

                        allText =  txtFile.responseText;
                        domore(allText,donePelicula);

                    }
                }
            }
            txtFile.send(null);
          }
```